# Why androidx.room.RoomDatabase is not recognised?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-room, gradle-dependencies

I'm learning modularity and in one of my modules `androidx.room.*` is not recognised. Downgrading Room version helps only with `@Database` annotation. Also, module seems to not see `Room.roomKtx` implementation because quick help suggest adding this implementation to `build.gradle`. My **kotlin version** is **1.6.21**

**ProfileDatabase.kt**

```
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.example.modules.Gift
import com.example.modules.Profile

@Database(
    entities = [Profile::class, Gift::class],
    version = 1
)
abstract class ProfileDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val profileDao: ProfileDao

    companion object {
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "profile_db"
    }
}
```

**build.gradle(:profileDatabase)**

```
apply {
    from("$rootDir/library-build.gradle")
    plugin 'kotlin-kapt'
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(':modules'))
    implementation Kotlinx.coroutinesCore

    implementation Room.runtime
    implementation Room.roomKtx
    kapt Room.compiler

}
```

**Room.kt**

```
object Room {
    private const val roomVersion = "2.4.2"
    const val runtime = "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion"
    const val compiler = "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
    const val roomKtx = "androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a wrong "module type". I used `apply plugin:'java-library'`,
 but should use `apply plugin:'com.android.library'`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct to me. But are you adding the Room dependecy in the correct build.gradle-file? You are imporing the "modules" module in the same gradle file as you are importing Room, I suspect that you have put the DB implementation in the module that you are importing.

Comment: The "modules" module contains a description of the room.Entities, which are Profile and Gift, and the one-to-many ProfileWithGift relationships.

Comment: Ok. I would put the whole DB implementation in the same module, not seperate implementation and entities. Name the module 'persistence' and keep Room out of your app module. If the app is unaware of the persistence implementation you are in a good place in a few years when you want to replace the persistence module.

Comment: I've done a quick reestablishment in modules to the form that You'vd presented but it's still the same problem. Maby there might be some unmatching versions in other dependencies? Now I've also downgraded kotlin version to 1.6.10 and room to 2.2.2.